# Installing libpuzzle windows wampserver

Tags: php, windows, wamp, wampserver

How do i install [libpuzzle](http://www.pureftpd.org/project/libpuzzle/) on a windows wampserver?
The readme says this:

```
Here are the basic steps in order to install the extension:

(on OpenBSD: export AUTOMAKE_VERSION=1.9 ; export AUTOCONF_VERSION=2.61)

cd php/libpuzzle
phpize
./configure --with-libpuzzle
make clean
make
make install

If libpuzzle is installed in a non-standard location, use:
./configure --with-libpuzzle=/base/directory/for/libpuzzle

Then edit your php.ini file and add:

extension=libpuzzle.so
```

How do i do this on windows with wamp?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For windows i.e. wamp, you will have to find a download site that has compiled it for windows PHP.

Make sure its been compile with VC9/10/11 if you are using a recent version of WAMP or VC6 if you are using an old version of wamp.

Most likely you will have to download the source code and compile it yourself, a much more complicated process, as I cannot find anywhere to download a pre-built windows version of this library.

Comment: @amdev Unfortunately there is nothing more to say. Basically you have to compile it for yourself.